# excel vba getelementsbyid can't get it to work

Tags: excel, getelementbyid, vba

I am new to objects and I have all of this working except the `htm.getelementsbyid`. When I get to the `rows.length` I get the error:

> run-time error 91, with object variable not set

```
Sub get_correct_address()

    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Dim htm As Object

    Set htm = CreateObject("htmlFile")
    row = 6
    StrNumCol = 4
    StrNamCol = 5
    StrTypCol = 6
    CityCol = 7
    ZipCol = 3
    StateCol = 8
    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", "http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=Verify&XML=          <AddressValidateRequest%20USERID=""968APPRA1046"">" & _
                    "<Address>" & _
                        "<Address1></Address1>" & _
                        "<Address2>" & CStr(Sheets("import").Cells(row, StrNumCol).value) + " " +    Sheets("import").Cells(row, StrNamCol).value + " " + Sheets("import").Cells(row, StrTypCol).value & "</Address2>" & _
                        "<City>" & CStr(Sheets("import").Cells(row, CityCol).value) & "</City>" & _
                        "<State>" & CStr(Sheets("import").Cells(row, StateCol).value) & "</State>" & _
                        "<Zip5></Zip5>" & _
                        "<Zip4>" & CStr(Sheets("import").Cells(row, ZipCol).value) & "</Zip4>" & _
                        "</Address>" & _
                    "</AddressValidateRequest>" & _
                    """, False"
        .send
        htm.body.innerhtml = .responsetext
    End With

    With htm.getelementbyid("comps-results")
       For x = 0 To .Rows.length - 1
           For y = 0 To .Rows(x).Cells.length - 1
               Sheets(1).Cells(x + 1, y + 1).value = .Rows(x).Cells(y).innertext
           Next y
       Next x
    End With

    'http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest%20USERID="xxxxxxxxxxxx">
End Sub
```

Comment: In addition to the answer provided by @Edward Bagby, you could put in a test condition above 'With htm...' that checks to see 'If .Rows.length > 0'  I recommend putting a break point in and stepping through the code watching the Locals Window.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot seem to open the object at the address in your code (it must be protected).  That said, the most likely problem is that htm.getelementbyid("comps-results") is returning nothing.  Verify the values and try stepping through your code with F8 and verify that .Rows.Length has a value.  If it does not, the problem may lie in the element ("comps-result") you are referencing.  Also verify that .Rows.Length is what you want.  Perhaps you want Rows.Count?

```
With htm.getelementbyid("comps-results")
   For x = 0 To .Rows.Count - 1
       For y = 0 To .Rows(x).Cells.Count - 1
           Sheets(1).Cells(x + 1, y + 1).Value = .Rows(x).Cells(y).innertext
       Next y
   Next x
End With
```